# Trying to wrap my head around the Unit of Work Pattern in c#

Tags: c#, unit-of-work

I'm trying to create a basic unit of work to fully understand the principles. I can re-factor later. I'm simply trying to get it working. I'm having some trouble.

I have a simple entity Code:

```
public class Code
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}
```

I have a CodeRepository with one simple Method.

```
public class CodeRepository
    {
        public Code GetByCode(string value)
        {
            // Go to DB and find code. Just using a sample.
            var code = new Code();
            code.Type = "Dx";
            code.Value = "20";
            return code;
        }
    }
```

I have a simple UnitOfWork class:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private CodeRepository _codeRepository;
    public CodeRepository CodeRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_codeRepository == null)
                _codeRepository = new CodeRepository();
            return _codeRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {

    }

    public void Rollback()
    {

    }
}
```

If I wanted to use the UnitOfWork to call my repository and get a code by name, I'd do:

```
var uow = new UnitOfWork();
var code = uow.CodeRepository.GetByCode("x");
```

Where is the connection created to use?  I'm uncertain where I need to go next. Also have to use ADO.NET.

**Update** 
Many of the folks below say that the connection should be opened in the repository. If for example, I needed to call 3 different GetBy methods in 3 separate repositories to get values for a view, would I want to open a new connection each time? Or, can I open a single connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would  create, open, use and close the connection at the last point where you actually retrieve it from the database, hence in `GetByCode`

```
public Code GetByCode(string value)
{
    // Go to DB and find code. Just using a sample.
    // assuming SqlConnection, store the connection-string f.e. in the settings
    string sql = "SELECT Columns FROM dbo.Table Where Value=@Value";
    using(var con = new SqlConmection(connectionString))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", value);
        con.open();
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Code code = new Code();
                // initiliaze it from the reader, f.e.
                code.Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What if I needed to call 3 different repositories to get values for a view. Would I want to keep opening and closing connections in each one? Or, could I use the same connection in all 3?

Comment: You can use the same connection for the same method, If the method calls another method which also retrieves data, it's probably betterto use a `try/catch/finally` instead and make the connection a private field.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could create the connection in the `GetByCode` method itself. You could potentially make it lazy load and not load until its data is actually referenced, but that probably over complicates things unless it is a requirement

However, this is a simple answer for a `Get` method. When it comes to persisting any changes, that would all be done in memory, and the connection would occur in the Commit.

Answer (score 0):

The repository that you are using is abstracting all the data access from you. So in the UoW class you do not care about connections, you just get a repository (ideally injected in the constructor) and use that. The repository on the other hand will handle the connection to db using your preferred data access method. Hope that makes sense...